"Error: useLocalStorage is a client-only hook" in next js 14
"useLocalStorage" is a client only hook
I'm using useLocalStorage hook from @uidotdev/usehooks. Even though HomePage.tsx file is set to "use client", I'm getting the following error:
 ⨯ Error: useLocalStorage is a client-only hook
    at HomePage (./src/components/HomePage.tsx:15:98)
digest: "1786536127"
 GET / 500 in 180ms

Even though the readme states that the hooks are "server-safe", I keep getting this error.
The minimal reproduceable code can be found at: https://github.com/Nusab19/mwc-useLocalStorageHook
The responsible code:
"use client";
import { useLocalStorage } from "@uidotdev/usehooks";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { Separator } from "./ui/separator";

const HomePage = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useLocalStorage("count", 0); // here's the problem

  return (
    <div className="...">
      <header className="...">Home Page</header>
      <Separator />
      <header className="...">Count: {count}</header>

      <div className="...">
        <Button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>Increment</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev - 1)}>Decrement</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => setCount(0)}>Reset</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

